# Estimate Ratio of Normalizing Constants from two datasets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains, sampling

Suppose I have a non-negative function $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to [0, +\infty)$ that defines two different (unnormalized) probability densities on two separate subsets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and, importantly, $A$ and $B$ are both compact, e.g. $A = [-1, 1]$ and $B= [-2, 2]$.

$$
\widetilde{p}(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if } x\in A \\ 0 & \text{if } x \notin A\end{cases}  \\
\widetilde{q}(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if } x\in B \\ 0 & \text{if } x\notin B\end{cases}
$$
Now suppose a set of samples from each
$$
x_1^p,\ldots, x_N^p \sim \widetilde{p}(x) \\
x_1^q, \ldots, x_N^q \sim \widetilde{q}(x)
$$
How can I use these samples to approximate the ratio of normalizing constants
$$
\frac{Z_q}{Z_p} = \frac{\displaystyle \int_B \widetilde{q}(x)dx}{\displaystyle \int_A \widetilde{p}(x)dx}
$$

Comment: If $x_1^p,\ldots,x_N^p\sim p(x)$ means that you sample from the distribution with density $p/\int p$, aren't you going to lose all the information about normalizing constants in your samples?

Comment: Yes most likely.. However I am hoping that if $A$ is a compact support (e.g. $A = [-1, 1]$) then there should be some way of dealing with this because in the end the normalizing constant is just the area under the curve..

Comment: At least you need some additional assumption like $\int f=1$. Otherwise I don't even see how you're going to distinguish $x_1^p,\ldots,x_n^p\sim p$ and $x_1^p,\ldots,x_n^p\sim 2p$ (which have the same distribution but different ratio of normalizing constants).

Comment: yes sorry, I forgot to write that! $\int f(x) dx = 1$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I'm afraid your problem is hard in general . Additional assumptions like $A$ being convex might help.